# Detect missing frequencies in a frequency distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-information, quantum-optics

I have photons with a frequency distribution where one frequency is completly cut out. For example a frequency distribution like that:

[image]

My question is: How precise can the position (frequency) of this gap be detected? In an experiment this gap is slightly shifted to the left or to the right (depending on the situation). I want to find out if this shifts can be detected (detect if there was a shift or not).

To give some numbers say $\omega_0 = 10^{15}\,\text{Hz}$ and the standard deviation of this double-humped distribution is given by $\sigma = 10^{10}\,\text{Hz}$. So the frequency $\omega_0$ is missing but very close to $\omega_0$ the distribution raises to its maximum. 
Now imagine that $\omega_0$ moves to the right like $\omega_0 \rightarrow \omega_0 + 10^{8}\,\text{Hz}$.

Is it possible to detect such shifts?

Comment: It's difficult (impossible actually) to provide an answer without knowing how well you know the parameters of this distribution (for instance are the left and right hand wings fixed or is the integral under the distribution fixed?) and how precisely your data are measured and with what resolution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just the integral is fixed, so if $\omega_0$ moves to the right the right peak goes a bit down whereas the left peak grows. The frequency distribution by itself is just a theoretical model so far. It is originated by an initial single-humped frequency distribution $|\psi(\omega)|^2$ centered around $\omega_0$ which is then multiplied by a $\sin^2$ which has a zero somewhere around $\omega_0$ (for example exactly at $\omega_0$ like in the graph). This is where the dip comes from...